# Facing issue while running appium script on android devices

Tags: java, windows, selenium, appium

Error on console

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error finding
>   if 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' is installed. Original error:
>   Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command
>   'C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -P 5037 -s 6219a1bc shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' exited with code 1'; Stderr:
>   'error: device '6219a1bc' not found'; Code: '1'
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>       System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KVSADD9', ip: '192.168.0.121', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_171'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
>       remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error finding
>   if 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' is installed. Original error:
>   Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command
>   'C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -P 5037 -s 6219a1bc shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' exited with code 1'; Stderr:
>   'error: device '6219a1bc' not found'; Code: '1'
>           at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
>           at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>       System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KVSADD9', ip: '192.168.0.121', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_171'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
>       org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details.
>   Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing
>   the command. Original error: Error finding if
>   'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' is installed. Original error:
>   Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command
>   'C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -P 5037 -s 6219a1bc shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' exited with code 1'; Stderr:
>   'error: device '6219a1bc' not found'; Code: '1'
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>       System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KVSADD9', ip: '192.168.0.121', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_171'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
>       remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error finding
>   if 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' is installed. Original error:
>   Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command

I am trying to run the script on real device. Most of the time script is not getting run and wherever script is running my device is getting restart automatically.

Any one facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like appium is not installing uiautomator2 server on your device, can you try the following and see if that works:

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7069#issuecomment-465940529